# Infinitely iterating the cosine function yields the Dottie number

Tags: functions, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

For simplicity’s sake, Let’s define our function to be cos(x).
For any value of x, iterating this function will yield some constant, take a calculator and try it.
But quite surprisingly, I recognized that number to be the solution to the equation cos(x)=x.
I do have an intuitive but not so rigorous answer though, and I may present it:
We will start by this really obvious equality
cos(cos(cos(cos(...cos(x)=cos(cos(cos(cos(...cos(x) (note that this iteration is infinite somehow, and it will be clear why in the next step)
Let’s set y=cos(cos(cos(...cos(x))
Substituting in our new variable yields this transcendental equation
cos(y)=y so y= 0.73908513322... (which is known as the Dottie number)
But does this apply to any function f(x)? I have so many questions.

Comment: The cosine has a unique fixed point, which is attracting. A typical function may have no fixed points, or several, and they may or may not be attracting.

Comment: Amazing! Really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given function $f : X \to X$, we call $x^*$ a **fixed point** iff $f(x^*) = x^*$. You've observed that $\cos : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ has a fixed point $x_0=0.73908\ldots$. Moreover, since for $\cos$ there is some interval $I$ containing $x_0$ such that $\cos^{(n)} x \to x_0$ (as $n \to \infty$), for all $x \in I$ (in fact, we can take $I = \Bbb R$ here), we call $x_0$ an **attracting** fixed point of $\cos$.

Some functions have no fixed points, let alone attracting ones: For example, for $$g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R, \qquad g(x) = x + 1,$$ there is no value $x^*$ such that $g(x^*) = x^*$. (Indeed, $g^{(n)}(x) = x + n$, so $g^{(n)}(x) \to \infty$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.)

Other functions have more than one fixed point. For example, the fixed points of $$h: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R, \qquad h(x) = x + \sin x,$$ are $x^* = k \pi$, $k \in \Bbb Z$, but $k \pi$ is an attracting fixed point only when $k$ is odd.

There are conditions that guarantee a given function $f : X \to X$ has some fixed point. A special case of the [Banach Fixed-Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) says that if $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a differentiable function and $I$ is some interval, and there is some $\alpha \in [0, 1)$ such that $|f'(x)| < \alpha$ for all $x \in I$, then $f$ has some attracting fixed point $x^* \in I$ and $f^{(n)}(x) \to x^*$ for all $x \in I$.

We cannot apply this result immediately to $\cos : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, since $\left\vert\cos'\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right\vert = 1$, so for $I = \Bbb R$ there is no $\alpha$ satisfying the above condition. But $\cos(\Bbb R) = [-1, 1]$, and on that interval, $|\cos'(x)| \leq \sin 1 < 1$, so the theorem tells us that there is an attracting fixed point $x_0$ in $[-1, 1]$, and we can conclude that $\cos^{(n)}(x) \to x_0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Can you provide me with some source for further read on this topic (papers, part of a textbook, ect..)? Really appreciated!

Comment: The best recommendation depends on your background, but one presentation of this material is found in Ted Shifrin's *Multivariable Mathematics: Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus, and Manifolds*, $\S$6.1. Incidentally Ted is a regular contributor on this site.

Comment: I am nowhere near a mathematician, I’m just a kid who is interested In math, that book is surely not for people on my level, thanks though!